# How to make an ADD function that curries to the nth integer

Tags: javascript, currying

How can I realize the below?

```
console.log(Sum(1))          // 1
console.log(Sum(1)(2))       // 3
console.log(Sum(1)(2)(3))    // 6
console.log(Sum(1)(2)(3)(4)) // 10
```

I've tried,

```
var add = function(x) {
    return function(y) { return x + y; };
}
```

But that's only good for one dive.

Comment: How exactly do you imagine `Sum(1)` to be `1`, but then `Sum(1)(2)` which is `1(2)` to make any sense?

Comment: I don't find any reason for which this question is downvoted...

Comment: @MaheerAli He is asking for something which is logically impossible, and not in any difficult-to-see way. Similar questions have also been asked over and over (see the dupe, but also e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279242/currying-function-with-unknown-arguments-in-javascript)). I come to the conclusion he simply didn't think/research about the issue for more than a few minutes, which is enough for me to downvote. Maybe he did, and just had a bad day (that happens to everyone sometimes!), but "eating a downvote" for one of these rare events is not too big a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to return a function with a `toString` method for getting a value, if not called as function.

```js
function sum(x) {
    function _(y) { x += y; return _; };
    _.toString = function () { return x; };
    return _;
}

console.log(sum(1))          // 1
console.log(sum(1)(2))       // 3
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3))    // 6
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)) // 10
```